how to prevent 'choose password for new keyring' message on ubuntu20.04 when using chrome from the terminal
I got this annoying thing when i am running some of my CI workflow that involves launching the browser.
i tried to add --password-store=basic to the /usr/shared/applications/google-chrome.desktop file after every Exec=google-chrome-stable, but this still does not work.
Could someone help with this? Thanks in advance!

Do you have auto login enabled for your desktop? If yes, that is the issue: on autologin, the system keyring is not automatically unlocked. You can then avoid the prompt by disabling the password for the keyring.

i ended up installing chromium instead of using chrome..
